# Formatted Text Color Options

Tags: arcgis-desktop, color, text

I'm trying to see what color options I have for formatted text for arcgis desktop 10.5. Mostly I'm trying to get these colors to work in a legend text string. I know the basic color options:

```
<CLR BLUE ='255'> TEXT </CLR>
<CLR GREEN ='255'> TEXT </CLR>
<CLR RED ='255'> TEXT </CLR>
<CLR YELLOW ='255'> TEXT </CLR>
<CLR MAGENTA ='255'> TEXT </CLR>
```

I know that you can lighten or darken the text color by adjusting the numerical value.

Are you somehow able get colors between the primary RGB and CMYK bands? For example, orange?

Comment: https://color.adobe.com/create choose your colour mode

Comment: Use the ArcMap color picker ESRI colors or RGB or HSV to pick you color. Switch to RBG mode to get the 3 values for that color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an orange color you should write the tag as follows:

```
<CLR red = '255' green = '110' blue = '10' > TEXT </CLR>
```

The output

[image]